# How can I improve this simple form?

Tags: forms, html, css

I have a simple form with 2 text fields and a search button.
I.e. something like this:

[image]

I don't like the checkbox as it is. How could I improve this better?

Comment: What does ASC stand for ?

Comment: Ascending. Default would be descending (i.e. checkbox not checked)

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to include a dropdown menu where descending is selected by default?

Comment: If it's only 2 options (ascending/descending) then using radios is a good option too. Checkbox doesn't make clear that the alternative to ascending is descending. I'd also avoid to use acronyms (and alternatives to make it clear, like A-Z vs. Z-A).

Comment: What is the relationship between the two conditions?

Comment: Can e.g. be a range: from - to

Answer (score 8):

With no further information this how you can improve your form:

- No abbreviation (*they can be obscure for the user*)
- No uncommon or useless symbols like [-] or [:] (*useless is useless*)
- Clear understanding of what is selected by default and what can be changed (*no ambiguity, no over-thinking*)

---

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffj3Ak.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

---

If descending and ascending are for the results then you may want to propose that option afterwards, once the results displayed

**edit:**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6dj8o.png)</sup>

The two buttons on the right are supposed to be segmented buttons. :-) They can be used before and after the search.

Comment: I like this.But why is `-` useless? If te condition is `from - to` for example why is the `-` useless?

Comment: I return you the favor: Why is the '-' useful? Does it add more meaning and bring less ambiguity? If not: it is not useful.

Comment: Well isn't it the way we write on paper? It seemed more intuitive to me. Am I wrong here?

Comment: You are not, it is just in the context the sign is replaced by the UI elements (text input). I edited with another mock with From - To.

Comment: You should leave out 'Ascendent' and 'Descendent' until the data is populated.

Answer (score 0):

The sorting of the results should be displayed after the results are shown. Currently, it's not very clear what the context for ascending is or how the results will be sorted - depends on what fields you will display for each result (name, date, type, other metadata); I'm guessing you'll have more than one field given that you have 2 search boxes.

Additionally, maybe you can try and leave only one search field and display the results something like this

```
search result 1   ...   condition A
search result 2   ...   condition A
search result 3   ...   condition B
search result 4   ...   condition A
search result 5   ...   condition B
```

and allow the users to sort also by the last column